# Activate virtualenv using alias

Tags: linux, shell-script, bashrc, virtualenv

I can activate my python virtual environment from it's folder by entering `. bin/activate`. I'd like to instead type a single word alias, such as `shazam`, from the home folder (or anywhere else) that activates the environment, changes to my master project folder, and lists my projects.

I tried creating an alias in .bashrc that pointed to an .sh file containing:

```
cd ~/path-to-virtual-environment
. bin/activate
cd ~/path-to-master-project-folder
ls -a
```

I was getting a permission denied error, so I ran `chmod u+x <script file>`. The script now runs, but the VE does not activate and while the project folders are listed, the shell is not in the master project folder. I would appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

NOTE:  I received an [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043081/8006793) on another forum. Shell scripts do not change the environment from which they're called; instead, use a shell function inside .bashrc.

```
shazam () {
  source ~/path-to-virtual-environment/bin/activate
  cd ~/path-to-master-project-folder
  ls -a
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alias can have list of commands:

```
alias shazm='source ~/path-to-virtual-environment/bin/activate; cd ~/path-to-master-project-folder; ls -a'
```

Comment: The alias has to be the other way round, at first the `cd` cmd and then the `source` cmd.

Answer (score 1):

This is a core feature of [the virtualenvwrapper package](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io), along with a robust, complementary featureset.

To create a virtualenv named `shazam` using virtualenvwrapper, simply:

```
mkvirtualenv shazam
```

To activate it:

```
workon shazam
```

To deactivate it, like any active virtualenv:

```
deactivate
```

Many use-cases and user configurations are possible using virtualenvwrapper. For instance, I prefer to keep all my virtualenvs in a single directory, `~/.envs`. This is supported as a configuration. It's an open source and actively maintained project, I can't recommend it strongly enough.